# Bootstrap radiobuttons in the same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make a `radio-inline` group of radiobuttons to align in the same line without stacking the class?

http://codepen.io/pablocgdev/pen/RKroZq

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="funkyradio">
          <label class="radio-inline"> <p>Output</p>

            <div style='display:inline;' class="funkyradio-success">
                <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio6" />
                <label for="radio6">P123F</label>
            </div>
            <div  style='display:inline;' class="funkyradio-success">
                <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio7" />
                <label for="radio7">ASDF</label>
                </label>

    </div>
```

If you add the style `display: inline` to your `div` tags like I did, that should get you to the desired result. I used inline css but you might want to add it to your css file. `display: inline` will use only the amount of space necessary to hold your element.

Comment: I also put <p></p> tags around the word Output to keep that above the radio buttons. If you don't want that then just remove them.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to put the radiobuttons in the same line in your example just by adding the following css code:

```
.funkyradio-success {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Since your radiobuttons are inside a div, you need to make sure they don't have `display:block` (their default value) so that they can be rendered in the same row.